# Not getting the visible tr's in a div with jquery 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, visible

I have to get all visible trs and do some operation on all its td's. So I was using

```
$('#divId tr:visible td')
```

to get the result. This was working fine till i was using jquery 1.4.2 but when i replaced it with 1.7.1, it stopped working.

http://jsfiddle.net/G9gZ5/10/

I checked, this is happening on all browsers

Comment: How are you making the `tr` elements invisible?

Comment: Your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/q5Kg4/

Comment: I tried there and its working fine. May be i downloaded the wrong file. I downloaded from http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery. Can someone please tell if i am using the right file

Comment: Debugged the jquery, it is giving an exception - "DOM Exception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)"

Comment: In your jsFiddle you have: `$('#dv tr:visible'*, '#dv')`, remove the 2nd #dv part and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you need :

```
var visibleTrs = $('#dv tr:visible').length;
$('#output').text('visible rows - ' + visibleTrs );
```